# On the relationship between non special Aronszajn trees and Suslin trees

Tags: set-theory

An $\omega_1$-tree $T$ is special if there is a colouring $c\colon T\to\omega$ such that whenever two nodes have the same colour they are incompatible. Equivalently a tree $T$ is special if it can be written as a countable union of antichains.

As usual I write Suslin tree instead of $\aleph_1$-Suslin tree and Aronszajn tree instead of $\aleph_1$-Aronszajn tree.

I know that if $T$ is a Suslin tree then $T$ is an Aronszajn tree which is not special (because antichains of $T$ are countable, so if $T$ were special it would have to be countable).

I also know that $\mathsf{MA}(\aleph_1)$ implies both that every Aronszajn tree is special (more precisely it implies that every tree of height and size $\omega_1$ without $\omega_1$-branches is special) and that there are no Suslin trees (because if there is a Suslin tree there is also a normal Suslin tree $P$, and $P$ is ccc while $P\times P$ isn't).

What I don't know but seems like a natural question is how to construct a Suslin tree from an Aronszajn tree which is not special, if possible, or how to construct a model with a non special Aronszajn tree but no Suslin trees, if the former isn't possible. In other words does "there exist a non special Aronszajn tree" imply "there exist a Suslin tree"?

**Edit:** After some reference chasing it turns out that Chapter IX of Shelah's "Proper Forcing" is titled "Souslin hypothesis does not imply imply "every Aronszajn tree is special"", which answers my original question. I'm writing this as an edit rather than an answer, because my question is now whether anyone has written down a more recent and understandable proof of this result?

Comment: I have a feeling that this comment will go unanswered, but I'd like the downvoter to let me know what they thought was wrong or improvable about the question

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316582/destroying-suslin-nothing-special and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162657/does-every-aronszajn-tree-has-a-suslin-or-a-special-subtree

Comment: @Asaf Thanks for the links, your question especially was very interesting to me. I just wanted something nice to think about while procrastinating on exams and phd applications, but it looks like I might actually have to read Shelah instead!